# Visual Basic No Data Exist for the row/column

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I've been searching for many references on this problem and I have nothing.. It's still have the same error, when i do login, then it will not having any problem, and after a while, the error will be shown so many times.

```
Call Koneksi()
    Try
        cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE username = '" & txt_username.Text & "' AND password = '" & txt_password.Text & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        rd.Read()
        If rd.HasRows = True Then
            txt_akses.Text = rd!hak_akses
            MsgBox("Welcome '" & rd!nama & "'", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
            MenuCustomer.txt_user.Text = rd!username
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_permainan WHERE status = 1", conn)
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            rd.Read()
            If txt_akses.Text = "Customer" Then
                If rd.HasRows = False Then
                    txt_username.Text = ""
                    txt_password.Text = ""
                    txt_akses.Text = ""
                    MenuCustomer.Show()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Permainan sedang berlangsung. Mohon Untuk login sesaat lagi", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
                End If
            Else
                MenuStaff.Show()
            End If
        Else
            txt_username.Text = ""
            txt_password.Text = ""
            txt_akses.Text = ""
            txt_username.Select()
            MsgBox("Username atau password salah", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
        End If
        rd.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

And here is my module named koneksi
    Imports System.Data.Odbc

```
Module CRUD
'Setting Koneksi
Public conn As OdbcConnection
Public cmd As OdbcCommand
Public ds As New DataSet
Public da As OdbcDataAdapter
Public rd As OdbcDataReader
Public dt As New DataTable
Public LokasiData As String
Public result As String
Sub Koneksi()
    LokasiData = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Database=db_bubble;server=192.168.1.14;uid=root"
    conn = New OdbcConnection(LokasiData)
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `rd.Read()` => this should have using loop, e.g. `While rd.Read() ... End While`.

Comment: I have made the way u said, And it show Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReader.HasRows` property check must precede the `DataReader.Read()` method, which should be enclosed in `While` loop because `DataReader` is forward-only stream (checking row availability immediately after `ExecuteReader()`). This example below is the correct way:

```
Try
    cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE username = @UserName AND password = @Password", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txt_username.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_password.Text)
    Using rd As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.HasRows = True Then
        While rd.Read()
            txt_akses.Text = rd!hak_akses
            MsgBox("Welcome '" & rd!nama & "'", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
            MenuCustomer.txt_user.Text = rd!username
            cmd2 = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_permainan WHERE status = 1", conn)
            Using rd2 As OdbcDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            If rd2.HasRows = True Then
            While rd2.Read()
                If txt_akses.Text = "Customer" Then
                    If rd.HasRows = False Then
                        txt_username.Text = ""
                        txt_password.Text = ""
                        txt_akses.Text = ""
                        MenuCustomer.Show()
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Game is in progress. Please login for a while", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
                    End If
                Else
                    MenuStaff.Show()
                End If
            End While
            End If
            End Using
        End While
    Else
        txt_username.Text = ""
        txt_password.Text = ""
        txt_akses.Text = ""
        txt_username.Select()
        MsgBox("Incorrect username or password", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
    End If
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Note that you should use different `DataReader` instances for this case, because in current code the second `DataReader` assignment overwrites the first. Also use parameters inside query to prevent SQL injection attempt.

Comment: It still showing No data exist for the row / column.. @Tetsuya Yamamoto

Comment: Well, I made a mistake by not checking second `DataReader` execution. Try apply check for that instance too. "No data exist" means that the `DataReader` is empty because no data fulfills `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: Do DataReader need to be closed?

Comment: Better to use `Using` statement to force automatic close on `DataReader` instance, if you don't want to do it manually.

Comment: How to use Using statement?

Comment: Try reading this reference: [Using Statement in VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). The corrected code already used that.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, is it correct the way I use it ? I have posted it in answer

Comment: Your `Using` statement still not correct, the `DataReader` instance must be declared inside the block to get it immediately disposed.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry, can u give an example please?

Comment: The example is already present in the answer - you need to declare both `OdbcDataReader` instances inside `Using` block for immediate disposal after the data reader is closed. The data is not exist in your example because you're calling `Read()` before checking with `HasRows`, and the data reader object is already closed at that time.

Comment: I have made change to the code, but it still show error.. Please look at the answer..

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code like this, and it still show error

```
        Using rd As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If rd.HasRows = True Then
                While rd.Read()
                    txt_akses.Text = rd!hak_akses
                    MsgBox("Welcome '" & rd!nama & "'", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
                    MenuCustomer.txt_user.Text = rd!username
                    If txt_akses.Text = "Customer" Then
                        cmd2 = New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_permainan WHERE status = 1", conn)
                        Using rd2 As OdbcDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                            If rd2.HasRows = True Then
                                MsgBox("Permainan sedang berlangsung. Mohon Untuk login sesaat lagi", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
                            Else
                                While rd2.Read()
                                    txt_username.Text = ""
                                    txt_password.Text = ""
                                    txt_akses.Text = ""
                                    MenuCustomer.Show()
                                End While
                            End If
                        End Using
                    Else
                        MenuStaff.Show()
                    End If
                End While
            Else
                txt_username.Text = ""
                txt_password.Text = ""
                txt_akses.Text = ""
                txt_username.Select()
                MsgBox("Username atau password salah", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Information")
            End If
        End Using
```

The error shown is looping..